# How to monitor Authentication with Angular 4, Firebase and Angularfire2?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I'm pretty new to Angular and programming in general, but I've put together a really simple Angular app with Facebook authentication. However even after reading the angularfire2 and Firebase documentation, I'm struggling to figure out exactly to show certain HTML elements on my page based on authentication state.

I want to avoid routing/views for the time being, as I'm learning and that's going to take me a while longer to understand well enough to implement.) For now, I'm trying to keep it simple for now by using *ngIf on individual elements. Is there a variable I can access from the component html to check if the user is logged in?

As you'll see in my code, it's kind of working right now when I use *ngIf that checks for the asynced user.uid variable displayed in the view. However, I'm trying to make it so the addLike click function in my app component export only executes if the user logged in, and if not, it will do something else.
How can I add this kind of conditioning to my code. How exactly can I access authorization state and use the result in my export class functions?

Below is the code for my component HTML and TS:

HTML

```html
<div style="text-align:center">
    <div class="row">
        
        
        <div *ngIf="!(user | async)?.uid" class="col-md-12 text-right">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="fblogin()">
            <i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            Sign in</button>
        </div>
        
        <div *ngIf="(user | async)?.uid" class="col-md-12 text-right">
            <span class="text-muted">You are Logged in!</span>
        <button class="btn btn-md btn-basic" (click)="logout()">Logout</button>
        </div>

    
    </div>
    
    
    
    
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <h1>
        Welcome to {{title}}
      </h1>
        </div>
  </div>


       
      

      
     





    <div class="row" *ngFor="let song of songs | async "> 

      <div class="col-md-12" *ngIf="song.np == true">
      <h4 class="dark">Now Playing: "{{song.title}}" - {{song.artist}}</h4>
      </div>
 
</div>



<h4>Tonight's Songs: </h4>
    
    
    
</div>
<div class="tablediv">
<table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Artist</th>
        <th>Likes</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let song of songs | async |  sortBy: 'likes' ; let i  = index"
[style.background]="song.np == true ? 'lightblue': 'white'"

  >

<td >{{ song.title }}</td>
<td >{{ song.artist }}</td>
<td [style.min-width]="'100px'" >{{ song.likes }}
 
            <i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"  *ngIf="song.likes < 1"></i>
         <i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true" *ngIf="song.likes >= 1"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true" (click)="addLike(song.$key, song.likes)"  ></i>
</td>

  </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

 <div class="hidden"> {{ (user | async)?.uid }} </div>

<button class="btn btn-md btn-basic" (click)="testAction()">Test</button>
```

TS

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable, FirebaseObjectObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { AngularFireAuthModule,AngularFireAuth} from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';

import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})


export class AppComponent {
    title = 'Oxcord';
    ngOnInit() {
    console.log("Dammit");
    }

user: Observable<firebase.User>;
  songs: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
  sizeSubject: Subject<any>;
   
   constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase, public afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
    this.songs = db.list('/songs');
    this.user = afAuth.authState;
   
   
  }
  

addLike(id: string, likes: number): void {

 this.db.list('/songs/').update(id,{ likes: likes +1 });
}
removeLike(id: string, likes: number): void {

 this.db.list('/songs/').update(id,{ likes: likes -1 });
}



fblogin() {
    this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider());
  }


  glogin() {
    this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
  }

  logout() {
    this.afAuth.auth.signOut();
  }

testAction(){


}





}
```